# Check_markup messes up urls/links

Tags: input-formats

I'm using the [check_markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/7) function when printing results from a custom textarea field. The issue I'm having is with urls/links.

If an url contains the scheme (i.e http.www.example.com) the output is just an empty `<a href></a>` element with an empty `href`.

If an url does NOT contains the scheme (i.e www.example.com) the output is `<a href>www.example.com</a>`. The link seems to works but the `href` is still empty.

I have checked the "convert url to links" option in the Text Format configuration and all other filters are applied to the text correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! May you edit your examples of absolute URL and relative URL? http.www.example.com is not an absolute URL, nor is www.example.com a relative URL.

Comment: Also, please add an explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions.